# What is the siginificance of [1] in FormData?

Tags: form-data

I'm inspecting `FormData` fields in HTTPS requests with Chrome. Here is what I see:

[image]

What is the significance of `[1]` in FormData?

Comment: Perhaps it's something to do with "URL encoding"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the HTML string's escape characters for the square brackets, as processed in the URL.  My guess is that [1] and [1][1] refer to array elements.

Comment: None. IIRC, PHP interprets them and creates arrays automatically. Other languages/frameworks don't.